# grep --after-context in perl

Tags: perl, optimization, grep

The code below works exactly as I want it to in my perl script. However, it takes forever to run through very large files. Would someone know a perl alternative to my grep command?

```
my $print = `grep --after-context=3 $line $inputfile`;
print OUTFILE $print
```

To explain the code above: it simply finds a line (called `$line`) in the input file (called `$inputfile`) and prints the match it found and the three lines following the match (from the `$inputfile`) to my outfile (called `OUTFILE)`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there's some overhead in launching a `grep` subprocess, it's a fixed amount, unrelated to the size of the file.  Unless you've got a very bad implementation of `grep`, you're not going to be able to improve the search time in pure Perl.  In fact, searching a large file using Perl is likely to be slower than `grep`, which is optimized solely for searching files.

If you're only looking for the first match, you might want to add `--max-count=1` to your `grep` command.  This will cause `grep` to quit immediately, instead of reading the rest of the file to find additional matches.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell your typical search patterns. Under certain circumstances you are able to speed things up with the `-F` option and disabling NLS by setting the environment `LANG=C`, read the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/) for the meaning.

Comment: The OP does seem to imply they have a fixed pattern, so `-F` is a very good suggestion - and even if the pattern isn't totally fixed, it's quite possible the regex used is unnecessarily complex.